# I can't upload large files in Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, rest

On the basic problem:
I am using Angular with ASP.NET API as backend where the files are sent.

When I upload the same file (4-10 MB) without Angular, the backend accepts it without any problem (Postman).
Only through Angular I can't upload files higher than about 4 / 6 MB, does anyone know why? (The file type is irrelevant).

```ts
let url_ = this.baseUrl + 'api/uploadFile';
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, '');

    const content_ = JSON.stringify(request);

    let options_: any = {
      body: content_,
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }),
    };

    return this.http
      .request('post', url_, options_)
      .pipe(
        _observableMergeMap((response_: any) => {
          return this.processUploadFiles(response_);
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        _observableCatch((response_: any) => {
          if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
              return this.processUploadFiles(response_ as any);
            } catch (e) {
              return _observableThrow(e) as any as Observable<DocumentMetadata[]>;
            }
          } else return _observableThrow(response_) as any as Observable<DocumentMetadata[]>;
        })
      );
```

(Generated by NSwag)

Error message:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
APIException Error\n at new ZoneAwareError An unexpected server error occurred.
```

My response at the backend output console is:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):
 {"name":"AppRequests","time":"2023-08-22T15:44:46.3217082Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"AFF-2302SN00693","ai.operation.id":"f0bfb1d8628785626a3b79bc9d1334f0","ai.operation.name":"POST
 /api/UploadFiles","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.21.0+5e2e7ddda9ec0e16a75b1ae0a37f6a13c777f5","ai.internal.nodeName":"AFF-2302SN00693"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"daa4fdc4602c662f","name":"POST
 /api/UploadFiles","duration":"00:00:00.0319042","success":true,"responseCode":"307","url":"http://localhost:4202/api/UploadFiles","properties":{"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests',
 Ver:'1.1')","DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Dev-Local"}}}}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you share any code at all?  This is a programming question/answer website. No one can help you with your code if you don't share your code.

Comment: I know this is a programming question site or I wouldn't have asked, right?

Comment: You have to read backend logs, if limit was hit it'll be there

Comment: Is the error coming back as an HTTP response, or is the Angular code itself erroring out?

Comment: @ChrisBarr
I've added the info at my question now :)

Comment: What do you mean `upload a file`? What you posted doesn't upload any file, it makes a POST request with a JSON payload. That's completely different from the `multipart/form-data` request sent by a form's file upload element. What did you actually try in POSTMAN?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few gaps for you to fill in with this answer's code but the answer to your question I believe is in HOW you are uploading the file in Angular. Postman requests use `multipart/form-data` for the most part unless you do some workarounds to send it in the body as a string. So based on you saying it works in Postman and seeing your code I think you will want to implement the `FormData` answer in your Angular code.

Some servers have max file sizes for the body of the request, so sending all these files in the body in the way you are could be getting blocked by the server because the body size is too large. For example:

- For servers using `Nginx`, you might need to adjust the `client_max_body_size` directive.
- For `Apache`, you might need to adjust the `LimitRequestBody` directive.

If you want to send a file to your .Net API you have a few options, but if you want it the most like Postman then the first option is probably what you're looking for. If you really want to keep it in the body (option 2) then I would suggest checking your server for body size limit like mentioned above.

1. Send it as `FormData` from the front end with a `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data` and receive it as an `IFormFile` in your .Net API:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

```
const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
// You can append other properties to the form if it's not only a file you want to send

let options_: any = {
      body: formData_,
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }),
    };
```

```
[HttpPost("uploadFile")]
public IActionResult UploadFile([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
   // Deal with file here
}
```

2. Send it as a something like a Base64 string:

```
    [HttpPost("uploadFile")]
    public IActionResult UploadFile([FromBody] FileUploadRequest request)
    {
        var fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(request.FileContent);

        // Now you have the file as a byte array. Process it as needed.
    }
```

```
fileToBase64(file: File): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}
```

```
   // Your other code...

   const base64String = await this.fileToBase64(file);
   
   const payload = {
       fileName: file.name,
       fileContent: base64String
   };

   const content_ = JSON.stringify(payload);

   let options_: any = {
      body: content_,
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }),
   };

   // The rest of your code
```

Although the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error might indicate a bad network connection or anything from this list and beyond:

- Network Interruptions
- Firewall or Security Software
- Server Overload
- Server Misconfiguration
- Proxy Servers
- VPN Issues
- Content Inspection
- Protocol Mismatches
- Expired SSL Certificates
- Server Application Errors
- Server Resource Limits